# I have a complex Dictionary to make a organized output but need to pass it to another module

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, dictionary

To begin, I'm BRAND new to Python and coding is difficult to begin with for me.

So I have a dictionary formatted (due to API) as below.

Keys and Values can be added so my guess is I need a loop of some sort.

```
agilityskills = {'Archery': {'Archery': 4, 'Crossbow': 6, 'Bow': 6}, 'Pistols': {'Pistols': 6, 'Semi-Automatics': 8, 'Holdouts': 8}, 'Gymnastics': {'Gymnastics': 6, 'Balancing': 8}, 'Blades': {'Blades': 5}}
```

I would like it to have a output as;

```
Archery(Bow)(Crossbow) >--------------------------------> 4(6)
Pistols(Semi-Automatics)(Holdouts) >--------------------> 6(8)  
Gymnastics(Balancing) >---------------------------------> 6(8) 
Blades >------------------------------------------------> 5
```

I don't want to print this, but pass it to another module, so maybe use the result be a function or variable?

Comment: what should be data type of output?? How another module use this output??

Comment: Incomplete specs: what strings would you want if e.g bow and crossbow, or semi-automatics and holdouts, had different numbers?  You're apparently showing a single number in parens for both and they happen to have equal numbers, but what would you want to format if the numbers were different?  Having the function return a list of strings is no problem, though there are plenty of difficulties in getting exactly the aligned formatting you want -- but the unsolvable part is the clarification request I'm asking!

Comment: @VivekSable The other module will put the variable or function into a table (Something like pretty table). Then the whole table will be printed.

Comment: If always 2 above, then there's really no need to store them -- it's totally redundant.  The formatting is too finicky for me to code so late at night (bedtime!), but the logic is simple if e.g returning a list of lists of skill names and a list of numbers e.g [ (['Archery', 'Bow', 'Crossbow'], [4, 6]), ...&c].  Then inserting the parentheses, the right number of dashes (by far the hardest part!), &c, to make the precisely-aligned strings you desire, would be the really messy, hard-word, probably-useless part.

Comment: @Paul: Can we give output in dictionary like `{"Archery": ["Archery(Bow)(Crossbow)", "4(6)"], "Pistols":["Pistols(Semi-Automatics)(Holdouts)", "6(8)", ....}` ??

Comment: @AlexMartelli  Hopefully I can describe the pattern accurately. So obviously I'm using this for a skills list. The First skill, IE, Pistols, will have a value of between 1-13. Those other keys inside the () will always have the same value, which  would be 2 above the first skill.

Comment: @VivekSable So, the other part of this dictionary is going to be passed to a module as well that will be for using the values as an integer. It'll take the value() and interpret it as a number of dice to roll. The values won't be just to be displayed.

Comment: @Paul, so your previous requirements were apparently about strings very precisely formatted -- now it seems the formatting is only part of it (thus it must be done separately!) and returning the strings and numbers separately (so they can be either formatted or otherwise used), as I suggested in my comment, might actually be, not just far simpler, but also far more useful -- right?

Comment: @Paul: Can we give output in dictionary like {"Archery": [("Archery", 4) ("Bow", 6), ("Crossbow",6)], "Pistols":[("Pistols", 6), ("Semi-Automatics", 8), ("Holdouts", 8), ....} ??

Comment: @AlexMartelli So, ultimately I can care less about the spacing, as that I can play around with later. So long as it is functional more than anything. Meaning the base skill is always followed with the specialties in () and the ratings the same.

Comment: @VivekSable Tried to input it as that, came back with a `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has clarified that the exact formatting can wait, so let's start with the "business logic", using `pprint` just for a more readable display of the first-stage results:

```
import pprint

agilityskills = {
    'Archery': {'Archery': 4, 'Crossbow': 6, 'Bow': 6},
    'Pistols': {'Pistols': 6, 'Semi-Automatics': 8, 'Holdouts': 8},
    'Gymnastics': {'Gymnastics': 6, 'Balancing': 8},
    'Blades': {'Blades': 5}
}

def refactor(ask):
    result = []
    for s in ask:
        ss = [s1 for s1 in ask[s] if s1 != s]
        skills = [s] + ss
        scores = [ask[s][s1] for s1 in skills]
        result.append([skills, scores])
    return result

pprint.pprint(refactor(agilityskills))
```

The result shown is:

```
[[['Archery', 'Crossbow', 'Bow'], [4, 6, 6]],
 [['Pistols', 'Holdouts', 'Semi-Automatics'], [6, 8, 8]],
 [['Gymnastics', 'Balancing'], [6, 8]],
 [['Blades'], [5]]]
```

which gives the skill names and scores in the desired groupings and corresponding orders, though not yet formatted as a single string per sub-list.  Note that the order of the sub-lists cannot be guaranteed -- it happens to "work" as desired here but that's random, as in general a `dict` cannot maintain order (and I do notice as it happens one "swap" between `Pistols` sub-skills -- if you run this code you may see others).

If order is important, it needs to be recorded separately (`collections.OrderedDict` can sometimes help, but I've seen it surprise coders in many cases, too -- so let's shift *that* to a separate future question, if need be:-).

Anyway, on to some formatting.  The desired output string for an entry is like:

```
Archery(Bow)(Crossbow) >--------------------------------> 4(6)
```

(the difficult part is only having the right number of dashes and I'm going to pass on *that* one!-).

So given the resulting nested list from the `refactor` above we can do *most* of the formatting easily...:

```
def withparens(ss):
    fss = [str(ss[0])]
    for s1 in ss[1:]:
        fss.append('({})'.format(s1))
    return ''.join(fss)

def formatit(rf, numdashes=6):
    result = []
    for skills, scores in rf:
        result.append('{} >{}> {}'.format(
            withparens(skills),
            '-' * numdashes,
            withparens(scores)))
    return result

result = formatit(refactor(agilityskills))

for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Now, this shows:

```
Archery(Crossbow)(Bow) >------> 4(6)(6)
Pistols(Holdouts)(Semi-Automatics) >------> 6(8)(8)
Gymnastics(Balancing) >------> 6(8)
Blades >------> 5
```

...which is **almost** the desired result, except that the number of dashes fixed at six (or any other single arbitrary value) clearly produces an ugly-looking result.  Rather, the number of dashes should vary for each line produced by `formatit`, in order to give the resulting nice alignment.  But doing that *generally* is hard, whence my punting:-).

Still, we can do a **little** better -- by thinking of the "length of the start of the line up to the `>`" which seems to be what the OP's question focuses on equalizing.  So...:

```
def formatitbetter(rf):
    result = []
    for skills, scores in rf:
        fsk = withparens(skills)
        numdashes = 53 - len(fsk)
        result.append('{} >{}> {}'.format(
            fsk,
            '-' * numdashes,
            withparens(scores)))
    return result

result = formatitbetter(refactor(agilityskills))

for line in result:
    print(line)
```

**Now**, running this shows exactly the result the OP asked for (if I've counted the number of dashes right, else, tweak that magic constant `53` to taste:-)...:

```
Archery(Crossbow)(Bow) >-------------------------------> 4(6)(6)
Pistols(Holdouts)(Semi-Automatics) >-------------------> 6(8)(8)
Gymnastics(Balancing) >--------------------------------> 6(8)
Blades >-----------------------------------------------> 5
```

Problem is, of course, that if some skill has many sub-skills with long names, this will not leave enough space for the dashes; and if we make lines longer some may be "too long" for whatever purpose the OP had in mind for this "pretty display" in the first place.  It's achieving generality in the presentation part that makes the presentation problem, in full generality, a difficult one!-)

(Nowadays most presentation will be using fonts that aren't mono-spaced, making things even harder, as the "visual" length of a string of text is not just the number of characters/glyphs in that text, but rather depends on the font's metric... enough for several headaches, especially to somebody like me, as I'm a highly-verbal, **non**-visual, thinker!-)

Comment: It worked perfectly. To answer your "had in mind" statement, I'm trying to make a MUSH. The server I have chosen works on Python. There was actually 8 different skill type list that I used your snippet for, and passed them onto a prettytable like function, that makes two columns and adds 1 skill type to one of the columns. So it breaks down to 2 columns, and 4 row like sections. Due to the size and width restrictions the >-> has been broken down and I just made it a simple - #(#) format.

Comment: So I've been playing around with this for a bit, working on add a [:10] to where I can crop the sub-skill down to ten characters, (I'll play with length). Where would I do that?

Comment: In `withparens`, change `fss.append('({})'.format(s1))` to `fss.append('({})'.format(s1[:10]))`.